# Google Analystics Messurement Protocol - ECommerce data does not appear

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I'm posting the following payload to the Google Analytics API :

```
v=1
t=transaction
tid=UA-157XXXXXX-X
cid=224ac375-3797-4512-9702-fcaf2cc9fdcb
ti=OD001
in=Panton%20Chair
iq=2
ic=PC
iv=Chairs
cd1=79123
```

but the posted data is not showing up correctly. 
The transaction is visible, but the product is not. 
What am I doing wrong ?

[image]

[image: Google Analytics Products]

Answer (score 0):

You need to send one measurement protocol hit for the transaction, and one for each item.

For example, your first measurement protocol hit would be:

```
v=1
t=transaction
tid=UA-157XXXXXX-X
cid=224ac375-3797-4512-9702-fcaf2cc9fdcb
ti=OD001
tr=1234.56
cd1=79123
```

Then you would send a

```
v=1
t=item
tid=UA-157XXXXXX-X
cid=224ac375-3797-4512-9702-fcaf2cc9fdcb
ti=OD001
in=Panton%20Chair
iq=2
ic=PC
iv=Chairs
cd1=79123
```

See more: https://www.optimizesmart.com/sending-ecommerce-data-via-measurement-protocol-google-analytics/

Also, as a side note, it might be better to upgrade to enhance ecommerce. There you could send it in a single hit